# Make Call - it call over and over and can´t be closed or end by button hang up

Tags: android, loops, call

today I tried to use following code in app and it make problem. When I call activity with this code, phone start calling (which is ok), but than it keep calling and calling and even if I try hang up with red button as always it end it and than it start calling again. It is like some kind of loop, but I never set any. Any idea, what is wrong?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);

finish();
}//protected void on...
```

Answer (score 0):

That makes perfect sense.

When you press the red button, you come back to the previous page, which in your case is this activity. It goes into the `onCreate()` again, and calls again.

Try to either:

1. place the call in the previous activity, not in the onCreate.
2. place the call in the action method of some button.